# Error trying to extract face region

Tags: opencv, face-detection

I have written the following piece of code to extract the image of the region detected as face using the OpenCV2.2 facedetect.c code.

```
//Extracting the image of just the ROI
        IplImage* rectImage;
        rectImage->roi=NULL;
        CvRect boundingBox={point1.x,point1.y,r->width,r->height};
        cvSetImageROI(rectImage,boundingBox);

        IplImage* originalBox=cvCreateImage(cvSize(r->width,r->height),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
        IplImage* reSizedBox=cvCreateImage(cvSize(100,100),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);

        cvCopy(rectImage, originalBox, 0);
        cvResize(originalBox,reSizedBox,CV_INTER_LINEAR);
        cvSaveImage("MyFaceBox.jpg", reSizedBox);
```

Problem: When I build it, it gives the following error:
"error: ‘cvResize’ was not declared in this scope"

I am using xcode as a developer tool. I cannot understand what is creating the problem. Can someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the relating header file, like

```
#include <imgproc/imgproc_c.h>
```